# Using SPEAK (or an alternative) to edit popup modal renderings in Experience Editor?

Tags: experience-editor, speak

I've been tasked with building Experience Editor support for a popup modal rendering for a site.

It was recommended by the architect on the project that we use the DialogWindow component of SPEAK to trigger a modal with just the popup rendering that could be edited in EE. I've spent the last few hours getting up to speed on SPEAK, and this seems like a lot of work to get this running; and I'm not sure it'll work, to be honest. I seem to have to set up a SPEAK app, a SPEAK page, use SPEAK components to load the rendering into a frame from what I can see. And we want to do this for multiple popups, so this a lot of work each time we add a new popup modal to the site.

Is there perhaps a simpler way of accomplishing this? The client wants to be able to edit popups in Experience Editor; which I know is a tricky request to handle. Anyone have suggestions on alternatives to handle this, or is SPEAK the way to go?

I'm using Sitecore 9.1.1.

Comment: Just don't initialize the modal in experience editor. Have the content at the bottom of the page and leave it inline. Much easier.

Comment: does EditFrame is not an option here?

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming MVC here)
If you are using controller renderings you can add logic in your controller to test for the current editor mode (i.e. IsExperienceEditor)

```
if (Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditor){
   return View("MyViewEdit", model);
}
else {
   return View("MyView", model);
}
```

This allows you to load a different View when the author is editing. Your edit view does not need to have the same markup as the end user experience so you can put your modal right there on the page for editing.

You may want to visually differentiate it somehow so the editor understands it is the modal content and not page content.

Comment: Since modals are typically hidden by default, my recommendation is to actually use what Jason mentions above in your View, and then apply an additional class to show the modal, but within the page in Experience Editor, so you can edit the contents.  Similar to what Richard commented above.